# How to increase data retrieval?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, query-performance

I have a query that takes long to execute and eventually times out.

My task is just to get all the data from the table for particular dates.

However, the database table does not have indexes on the date column and query takes long time to execute and times out.

This is piece of code I have:

```
DateTime dateTo = Convert.ToDateTime(data.DateTo);
DateTime dateFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(data.DateFrom);
command.CommandText = "select * from errorlog where errortime between @dateFrom and @dateTo";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTo", dateTo);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateFrom", dateFrom);
da.SelectCommand = command;
da.Fill(ds);
```

Is there any way to rewrite the logic to improve the performance?

Comment: add the indexes on the date columns? And don't use * in your select if you really want things to perform.

Comment: The "correct" approach is to work with your DB Admin so the query doesn't time out!  If the query needs indexes - your organization should probably add the indexes.  In the meantime, probably the best you can do is ask for a smaller result set ("between dateA and dateB", then "between DateC and Date D", etc).  BTW: *ONLY SELECT THE COLUMNS YOU ACTUALLY NEED!!!!*.

Comment: What makes you think this issue is C# related? If you run the query without C# but with a database tool, do you have the same problem? Probably. However, your question refers to C# so maybe you have a reason to assume that it is C# related.

Comment: Yes, it runs for too long as well

Comment: Run the query directly on the DB to know whether you need DB optimization or query optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Talk to your DBA. Let him create the index. All other things you are going to 'fix' because of this is just a waste of your time and the time of your users.

Answer (score 0):

Since the query timeout happens because of slow database, few solutions are:

1. Increase the timeout value;
2. Execute the query in the database first as usually they cache the results. This will warm up the data for you, however, I totally understand that, it may not be always possible;
3. Run query in loop going over the entire date range in chunks and then consolidate your result at your application's end;
4. Get only the required columns instead of everything.

Comment: What about just adding the index?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: OP hates them... (see his question, he is aware of not having indexes already)